# Excel VBA: Date Format when I bring a date into a listbox and out to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, date, listbox

I've spent the last few hours trying to get this sorted out.. without luck.  I have a spreadsheet with 68 columns, and 200 rows.  I've got a Userform that I can edit the sheet with, and also populate another set of sheets with filtered reports.  It all works except for the dates.  I'm in the UK, and need dd/mm/yyyy.  The date comes in to the UserForm correctly, as can be seen by the little art gallery below, but when I export it out to another sheet, be that back to the Source sheet as an edit, or to the other sheets to generate the report sheet, it changes to mm/dd/yyyy.  I've tried changing the date format in the sheets, with both standard and custom settings.. the ones that are meant to force everything to sysdate or en-GB, but nothing I've tried works.  Here are a few small images of what's going on..

This is the cell on the source sheet..
[image]

This is the Text Box on the User Form
[image]

..and when sent to the Report Sheet looks like this.  [image]

This is the change of date in the Text Box
[image]

But when sent back to the source sheet, shows as
[image]

And now the code..

This is the UserForm Initalise code..  For each snippet, I've just included the line that corresponds to the one cell of data, rather than put all 68 lines in.  [image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ListBox1.List = Range("data_table").Value
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = UBound(ListBox1.List, 2) + 1
      ListBox1.TabStop = False
    ListBox1.ColumnHeads = False

  TextBox8.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 18)

End Sub
```

This is to format the TextBox correctly, but as it displays correctly whether it's commented out or not, then it's probably not doing anything?

```
Private Sub Listbox1_Click()
Dim cell As Range

    Me.TextBox8.Text = Format(TextBox8.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")

End Sub
```

This is the code to write to the Report Sheet, which takes the listbox data, once it's been filtered by row using a ComboBox, and by column, exporting the date from the column corresponding to the line(s) in the code below.  It generates a choice of 15 different reports, depending on the columns chosen, which will eventually be created as a PDF for the users.

```
Private Sub C_Btn_FullReport_Click() 
Dim lItem As Long
 Sheets("Report_All").Rows("3:300").ClearContents
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False     
     For lItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
     Worksheets("Report_All").Columns("A:CA").AutoFit
   Worksheets("Report_All").Rows("3:300").AutoFit
 With Worksheets("Report_All")
  .Rows("3:300").HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft

     .Cells(lItem + 4, 13) = ListBox1.List(lItem, 18)

  .Columns("A:CA").AutoFit     
 Unload UserForm1
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End With
 Next lItem
 End Sub
```

In the last snippet, I tried the following, both before and after the particular list/cell reference..

```
.ListBox1.List(lItem, 18) = Format(DateValue(ListBox1.List(lItem, 18)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Above the line it gave a Run Time Error 13, and below, RTE 438.

There is a lot more to do with this project, but I can't get on until I can get the dates sorted out.

Thanks in advance..

Liam

Comment: What are your windows regional short date settings?  Is it the format that is changing?  Or is the actual date changing? (check this by formatting the worksheet with an unambigous format (eg `dd-mmm-yyyy`).  If the date format doesn't change when you do this, then you are writing strings.  Be sure to check on the **Source** worksheet as well as the results sheets.